# Change Number of Categories between Tick-Mark Labels on Chart X-axis

Tags: vba, ms-access

If I have more (or less) data in my Access 2010 graph, I want to decrease (or increase) the number of tick marks on the X-axis. I looked for the right syntax but I couldn't find it.

I did the same for the Y-axis Title and that works fine:

```
me.Graph1.Object.Axes(2,1).AxisTitles.Caption="g/ml"
```

For number of tick-marks of the X-axis; I've tried a number of words can not find the right one. It stopped at:

```
me.Graph.Object.Axes(1,1).Scale.???????? (I want a number of categories = 3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Example code from my db for XYScatter chart. xlCategory is for X-axis and xlValue is Y-axis.

1. this procedure is in a standard module and called by a form and a report

```
Sub FormatProcGraph(strObject As String, strLabNum As String, booMetric As Boolean, dblOMC, dblMDD)
'format Proctor graph on form and report
Dim obj As Object
Dim gc As Object
Dim intMaxD As Integer
Dim intMinD As Integer
Dim intM As Integer
If strObject Like "Lab*" Then
    Set obj = Reports(strObject)
Else
    Set obj = Forms(strObject).Controls("ctrProctor").Form
End If
Set gc = obj("gphDensity")
intMaxD = Nz(Int(dblMDD), 0)
intMinD = Nz(Int(DMin("D", "GraphProctor", "Source='Lab' AND LabNum='" & strLabNum & "'")), 0)
With gc
'format y axis scale
If booMetric = True Then
    intMaxD = intMaxD + IIf(intMaxD - intMinD < 125, 50, IIf(intMaxD - intMinD < 250, 25, 0))
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = intMaxD
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = intMaxD - 250
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 50
    .Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 10
Else
    intMaxD = intMaxD + IIf(intMaxD - intMinD < 6, 2, IIf(intMaxD - intMinD < 10, 1, 0))
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = intMaxD
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = intMaxD - 10
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 2
    .Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 0.4
End If
'format x axis scale
If Int(dblOMC) > 6 Then
    intM = Int(dblOMC) + IIf(dblOMC - Int(dblOMC) >= 0.5, 1, 0)
    .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = intM + 7
    .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = intM - 5
End If
'y axis label
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
If booMetric = True Then
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Dry Density, kg/cu.m"
End If
End With
End Sub
```

2. this procedure is behind report

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
'format graphs
Dim MinUWT As Double, MaxUWT As Double
Dim MinDry As Double, MaxDry As Double
Dim MinSoak As Double, MaxSoak As Double
Dim MinRat As Double, MaxRat As Double
With Me
If Not IsNull(!MinOfA) Then
    MinUWT = Int(!MinOfU) - IIf(!MaxOfU - !MinOfU <= 2, 3, 1)
    MaxUWT = MinUWT + 8
    MinDry = Int(!MinOfD / 5) * 5 - (40 - Int((Int(!MaxOfD / 5) * 5 + 5 - Int(!MinOfD / 5) * 5) / 10) * 10) / 2
    MaxDry = MinDry + 40
    MinSoak = Int(!MinOfS / 5) * 5 - (40 - Int((Int(!MaxOfS / 5) * 5 + 5 - Int(!MinOfS / 5) * 5) / 10) * 10) / 2
    MaxSoak = MinSoak + 40
    MinRat = Int(!MinOfR / 5) * 5 - (40 - Int((Int(!MaxOfR / 5) * 5 + 5 - Int(!MinOfR / 5) * 5) / 10) * 10) / 2
    MaxRat = MinRat + 40
    .gphWeight.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinUWT
    .gphWeight.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxUWT
    .gphITSdry.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinDry
    .gphITSdry.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxDry
    .gphITSsoak.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinSoak
    .gphITSsoak.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxSoak
    .gphITSret.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinRat
    .gphITSret.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxRat
    If Me!Metric = True Then
        .gphWeight.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Unit Weight, kg/cu.cm"
        .gphGradation.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Sieve Size (mm)"
        .gphITSdry.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "ITS Dry, kg/cu.cm"
        .gphITSsoak.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "ITS Soaked, kg/cu.cm"
    End If
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it this weekend

Comment: I’ve tried it., but i get an error: unable to get the axes property of Chart class. The code i wrote: me.Graph1.object.axes(xlValue).maximumscale=3

Comment: I edited answer to show complete procedures. Note `.Object` is not used.